# create custom html footer inn tcpdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, tcpdf

I would like to create an html footer with tcpdf.
I found this documentation to create a custom footer:
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_003/

But I have no idea how I can realize it with this html content:

```
<table class="tblFooter" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Box 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Box2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Box3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: The code you linked uses PHP code `$this->SetY(-15);` to put the cursor to the bottom of the page. In your question there is just a html table. How do they fit together? What is a "custom footer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extend the TCPDF class to add custom Header-Footer. Providing an example for your reference.

```
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

        public function Header() {
        
            $hdrhtml ='
                
                <br /><br />
                
                <table border="0" width="650" cellspacing="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <br />
                            <font style="font-size: 10px;"><b>Some text<br /></b></font>
                            <font style="font-size: 10px;">Some Text</font>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            ';        
        
          $this->writeHTML($hdrhtml, true, false, true, false, '');
        
        }
        
        public function Footer() {
        
          $fhtml = '
            <table class="tblFooter" cellpadding="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Box 1
                </td>
                <td>
                    Box2
                </td>
                <td>
                    Box3
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
          ';
          
          $this->writeHTML($fhtml, true, false, true, false, '');
          
        }

}

$pdf                = new MYPDF('P', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins, left-top-right
$pdf->SetMargins(20, 10, 10);

// remove default header/footer
//$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
//$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 50);
```

Comment: thank you very much !! :)